Twenty Twenty-Four: Static Front Page with Post Links
The post links show nicely in the edit (using blog home template writer pattern):

wp-admin/site-editor.php?postType=wp_template&postId=twentytwentyfour%2F%2Ffront-page&canvas=edit

The post-title and post-excerpt blocks won't show on the front page with the current selections, can this be changed?
The lead comment on this question suggests it is not possible by default, thus it points to the functionality of the theme.
